# GoogleAppEngine - query with some custom filter

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am quite new with appEnginy and objectify. However I need to fetch a single row from db to get some value from it. I tried to fetch element by `ofy().load().type(Branch.class).filter("parent_branch_id", 0).first()` but the result is `FirstRef(null)`. However though when I run following loop:

```
for(Branch b : ofy().load().type(Branch.class).list()) {
    System.out.println(b.id +". "+b.tree_label+" - parent is " +b.parent_branch_id);
};
```

What do I do wrong?

[edit]
Ofcourse Branch is a database entity, if it matters parent_branch_id is of type long.

Comment: What result do you get with your loop ?

Comment: Result is just a list of branches (well, tree nodes actually) formated according to the system.out.println: `[long] [node_name] - parent is [long]`

Comment: Do you have parents with id 0 ? What kind of id is it ? Auto ids from Objecitfy ? Because in that case, I think there is no way you get a 0 id...

Comment: Ids are indeed auto from objectify but the column parent_branch_id points at other record in the same table (its not required and acts as foreign key). And yes, there is one record with 0 in this field.

Comment: Please add the definition of your Branch class; chances are you are missing an @Index or perhaps you have some other misconfiguration (@Parent on parent_branch_id? Perhaps it is not a number?).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `Branch` as the result of your request, I think you miss a `.now()`:
`Branch branch = ofy().load().type(Branch.class).filter("parent_branch_id", 0).first().now();`

Comment: `cannot find symbol
  symbol: now()
  location: class Ref<Branch>   `

Comment: I have never used Objecify 4, even if I now the version 3 pretty well. Can you replace the `.now()`by a `.get()` or is that an error too ?

Comment: I can replace now with get but it still returns null instead of result even though there is one record that should match the filter...

Comment: Have you `@Index`ed you `parent_branch_id` field in your Branch class ?

Comment: Yes I think so... in Objectify 4 all the variables are unindexed by default. I you want to query a field it has to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have an `@Index` annotation on your `parent_branch_id` property.  When you do `ofy().load().type(Branch.class).list()`, Objectify is effectively doing a batch get by kind (like doing `Query("Branch")` with the low-level API) so it doesn't need the property indexes.  As soon as you add a `filter()`, it uses a query.

Assuming you are using Objectify 4, properties are not indexed by default.  You can index all the properties in your entity by adding an `@Index` annotation to the class.  The [annotation reference](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/AnnotationReference) provides useful info.

Comment: @Moby04 If instead of `first()` you use `list()`, but keeping the `filter()`, do you get expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Example from the [Objectify API reference](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/DesignObjectify4#API_examples):

```
LoadResult<Thing> th = ofy.load().type(Thing.class).filter("foo", foo).first();
Thing th =       ofy.load().type(Thing.class).filter("foo", foo).first().now();
```

So you need to make sure member "foo" has an @Index and use the now() to fetch the first element. This will return a null if no element is found.

May be `"parent_branch_id"`in your case is a long, in which case the value must be 0L and not 0.